# Winform control value defaulting and validation

Tags: c#, winforms

hope this is an interesting question:

Let's say I have designed a Dialog using winform which contains a number of controls.

(1) When this dialog is opened, I want to set default values to all controls. However, value of one control could depend on the value of another control (or some of other controls).

(2) When user has changed the value of one control, I want to validate the new value in the overall context. In other words, I have many rules saying what combinations of values are acceptable (if control A has value 1 and control B has value 2 then control C must not have value 3)

Let's assume for now that I can guarantee that all "rules" defined by me will not end up in a dead loop.

My question is: is there any known framework or common practice for handling this in a general way? I dont want it to be specific to this particular dialog I created. I want it to be such a framework that I simply define "rules"-rules saying what combinations are invalid and rules saying what is the inferred value of a control-and the framework will evaluate these rules whenever control value chagnes.

Any idea or comment is welcomed  :)

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what rules you are wanting 1 or 2 examples would be nice

Comment: All the rules are normally in the form: if (controlA.Value is within some list && controlB.Value is within some other list) then controlC cannot have value xxx. To be specific, consider this example: say we have dialog where user can select products from amazon, input quantity and price. We also show the balance of user's account on the dialog. A rulecould be: if product.SelectValue is  within a discount list, price will be the original price times 0.8.

Comment: Another rule could be quantity * price must be less than account balance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a name for this pattern or even if it a best practice, but I have generally handled it in the following way. I only show a single control, but the design easily supports adding more controls.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private EventHandler textBoxChanged;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);

        textBoxChanged = new EventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged);
    }

    void setEventHandlers() {
        textBox1.TextChanged += textBoxChanged;
    }

    void removeEventHandlers() {
        textBox1.TextChanged -= textBoxChanged;
    }

    void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        checkAndUpdate(sender as TextBox);
    }

    void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // set minimum required set of default values ...

        setEventHandlers();
        checkAndUpdate(null);
    }

    private void checkAndUpdate(Control userModified) {
        removeEventHandlers();

        // enforce rules
        //   if rules are violated, you can notify the user 
        //   of the offending control: userModified

        // update dependent controls

        setEventHandlers();
    }
}
```